# Are there shiny functions like conditionalPanel that expose input generally?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

`conditionalPanel` is a convenient method to wrap a javascript expression that returns a boolean value in order to show or hide HTML objects. Is there something more general that exposes `input`? And if not, why not?

Suppose you've got a slider and a plot that you want to manually fade out. It would be convenient to have a function, say, `jsExpr`, and write something like:

```
sliderInput("opacity", "Opacity", min=0, max=0.5, value=0.2, step=.1),
div(style=paste0('opacity:',jsExpr("input.opacity*2")), plotOutput("myPlot"))
```

Here, I've added a `*2` to the expression just to emphasize that I want to use arbitrary computed values from `input`. If `conditionalPanel` can show/hide based on boolean javascript expressions, why not more generally as above?

The best alternative solution seems far more complicated using shinyjs. For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

adjustOpacity <- "shinyjs.adjustOpacity = function(params) {
$('.myplot').css('opacity',params)
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text=adjustOpacity),

  sliderInput("opacity", "Opacity", min=0, max=0.5, value=0.2, step=.1),
  div(class="myplot", plotOutput("myPlot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({ plot(faithful, pch=15) })

  observeEvent(input$opacity, {
    js$adjustOpacity(input$opacity*2)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```